# Start .vbs script without icon of wscript.exe in the taskbar

Tags: wsh

How can I Start .vbs script without icon of wscript.exe in windows taskbar

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the `CScript.exe`, Windows does not show the `WScript.exe` host executable icon by default (shows `Popup`, `MsgBox`, `InputBox` and `Echo` only). Check the difference:

```
start "" cscript 30598853.vbs
```

will show a Windows script host icon in the Windows taskbar whilst

```
start "" wscript 30598853.vbs
```

will not. In both cases, an *additional* Windows script host icon will appear for a while (i.e. for the duration of the `Popup` is active in given example)...

Create a sample `30598853.vbs` script as follows:

```
Dim WshShell, BtnCode
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
  BtnCode = WshShell.Popup( _
    WScript.ScriptName & vbNewLine & "Exit script?" _
    , 5 _
    , WScript.FullName _
    , vbOKCancel + vbQuestion)
  If BtnCode = vbOK Then Exit Do 
  Wscript.Sleep 15000
Loop
```

**Edit**

To the best of my belief, a window invoked via `Popup` method or `MsgBox` function or `InputBox` function (and `Echo` method in case of the `WScript.exe` host executable as well) will *always* show it's icon in the taskbar. This happens regardless of that  particular window is *on top* or isn't.

Read in another forum that one could [assign a fully transparent icon to a particular executable](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/181802-taskbar-pin-invisible-icon-program.html)...

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Is there any chance to remove that icon when the popup is active? May be there is any vbs code something like WinHide (TrayHide) exist?